# Relationship between unicode and UTF-8 / 16 / 32

Tags: terminal, encoding, unicode, charset

I don't understand the relationship between UTF-8 and its other variants and am getting anomalous results at the terminal. For example, right arrow is:

`0xE2 0x86 0x92` in UTF-8

but it is

`0x2192` in UTF-16 and Unicode

I don't understand how E28692 is equivalent to 2192.

Also, the UTF-8 version does not seem to work in my linux terminal, which is using UTF-8 encoding with DejaVu font that supports Unicode. For example, if I enter

`echo -e "\u2192"`

Then I get an arrow, great, correct, it works. But, if I enter

`echo -e "\xe2\x86\x92"`  or

`echo -e "\x00\x00\x21\x92"`

Then I get incorrect graphics. Why are my hex sequences wrong?

Comment: You're confusing the charset and the encoding to encode that charset's characters [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222386/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-unicode

Comment: `I don't understand how E28692 is equivalent to 2192.` That statement is invalid. The problem is that one is not *equal* to the other, but rather, one is **mapped** to the other. Unfortunately, I too am still at a loss of whether there is any sort of formulaic mapping function, or if it is just some giant look-up table. From what I can tell, there [does seem to be some logic to it](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-4) (though not a nice, easy one).

Answer (score 3):

### Unicode code points encoded into UTF-8

They're equivalent because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description, see the algorithm for converting Unicode code points to UTF-8.  It goes like this.

Your code point [0x2192](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2192/index.htm), is between U+0800 and U+FFFF.  So we use the third row of the table.

```
                         Byte 1     Byte 2      Byte 3
16  U+0800  U+FFFF  3   1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

0x2192 in binary is `0010 0001 1001 0010`.  Let's plug that in, then convert those back to hex

```
16  U+0800  U+FFFF  3   11100010    10000110    10010010
                    3   E   2       8   6       9   2
```

E28692 in other words.

### Escape sequences in your shell

Now as to why your shell doesn't display the right arrow when you enter a UTF-8 sequence, let's look at the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).  Search for the section on the escape sequence `\xHH` and you'll fint it described as

> the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)

So you're asking bash to display three separate two character sequences, probably giving you something like [LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e2/index.htm), [START OF SELECTED AREA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/86/index.htm), and a [private use character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm) of some sort.

Comment: So, if I want to enter the UTF-8 code in the UTF-8 terminal how do I do that ?

Comment: I don't think you can with an echo, judging from the documentation.

Comment: It looks like [nowadays you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash).

Answer (score 3):

**Unicode is a character set. UTF are encodings.**

Unicode defines a set of characters with corresponding code points, ie. values that unambiguously identify characters in Unicode character set.

For example according to [unicode-table.com](http://unicode-table.com/en/) `U+0041` corresponds to capital A, `U+03A3` is greek capital sigma (Σ) and `U+2603` is a snowman (☃). `U+` numbers are code points. Unicode tells us what symbol corresponds to what code point, but doesn't tell us how to encode those code points in bytes.

This is where UTF (Unicode Transformation Format) comes into play. UTF is an encoding: it maps Unicode code points to unambiguous byte sequences.

- UTF-32 is the "dumb" encoding. All Unicode code points are at most 4 bytes long, so UTF-32 simply interprets code point as a 4-byte number (32-bit, hence the name) with [big endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). So `U+2603` is encoded as `0x00002603`.

  UTF-32 is very simple, but also very redundant. Most commonly used characters fall in ASCII range and are represented by code points 0-127 in Unicode, so in UTF-32-encoded files almost 3 in 4 bytes will be zeros. Almost every English sentence becomes 4 times longer (in bytes) when encoded in UTF-32 instead of ASCII.
- UTF-8 (very common on the Internet) uses only 1 byte for ASCII characters, so it doesn't introduce any overhead in ASCII-only files (every ASCII file is also a UTF-8 file with the same contents). Other characters require up to 6 bytes.
- UTF-16 (used by Windows, just to name one example) is a compromise between UTF-32 and UTF-8. Code points are encoded to either 16-bit or 32-bit sequences. It's more redundant than UTF-8 in most cases, but easier to maintain and faster to process.

Different characters may have different representations in different UTF-x encodings. For example UTF-8 sequences may span up to 6 bytes, while UTF-16 sequences are at most 4 bytes long, even though both encode the same character set (Unicode). More fine-grained encodings (UTF-8) use more bits to indicate sequence length, so for high code points encoded values are longer and less optimal.

[dsolimano's answer](https://superuser.com/a/826153/194694) has the explanation of your shell's behavior.

Comment: actually UTF-8 will be at most 4 bytes long for all Unicode codepoints. 5 or 6-byte sequence is used to encode values more than 21 bits